# Hair Mesh vs. Hair Particles: Which is either on my computer?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, particles

I'm debating on whether to make the hair for the model I'm making as a mesh or particles. Are there any differences when it comes to things like computer usage and render times?

Comment: Hard to track in these days all speed ups, but mesh hairs should be still faster solution ... the easiest way is to test by your self  how your comp reacts :)

Comment: i would also think about using geometry nodes. It is often much more flexible and quicker than particles.